# Regexp to check for consecutive spaces

Tags: php

I'm banging my head to the table in trying to write a regular expression that filter out strings that contain only Swedish letters, hyphens and single whitespaces - that is, not two in a row. I've got this `preg_match('/^[A-ZÅÄÖa-zåäö-]+\s{1}$/',$b)` and I feel like I've tried a hundred different models, but it's not working. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Give example of sentences that match and sentences that should not match

Comment: I think I can help, but I have no clue what you are trying to match. Could you explain (and give examples) of strings that *would* match and strings that *would not* match?

Comment: This is unrelated to the question, but you should use the `u` switch for it to work correctly if your source (and text) is in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often the best way to solve a problem like this is splitting it into **two** separate regular expression checks.

- check that the string contains only the letters you want (and whitespaces)
- if the first check passes, check that it doesn't have two or more consecutive spaces

Try:

```
if ( preg_match('/^[A-ZÅÄÖa-zåäö-\s]$/',$b) && !preg_match('/\s\s+/', $b) ) {
    /...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works :) But I got another answer that managed it all in one expression.

Comment: But I'll give you this one anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple spaces (two or more) is {2,} so try to replace your {1} with that and run it again.

Comment: He said he *doesn't* want to match 2 spaces.

Comment: @eykanal, I think the real problem is no one knows what he wants to match...I don't even know if *he* knows what he wants to match, thus the difficulties :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you should re-read what the regexp does and that there's 1 space being taken into account, not two or more. Also, negations are trivial operation when it comes to anything related to computers.

Comment: @furicane - If it was a negation, it would be `[^...]`. As it is, he's using the `^` and `$` to specify the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, everyone, I should've been more clear. I negated the preg_match.

Comment: And was looking to `die();` should the string contain anything else than the characters I specified

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your regex looks for a word with those characters and then a single space. If you're looking for a way to capture things like `[word][single space][word][single space]`, you may want to try

```
/^([A-ZÅÄÖa-zåäö-]+\s{1}?)+$/
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clearer, thanks for the answer, though, but it wasn't really this that I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer that worked perfectly, but it disappeared... Anyway, this code did the trick `!preg_match('/^(?:[a-zåäö-]+|\s(?!\s))+$/i',$b)`